# sql query to get the COUNT and MAX results numbers from a table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to write a sql query to select the top 10 trending pages on my website for the last minute. My table is named `trending`. Every time a user visits a page, a record will be entered to that table with the time of that visit. Something like this:

```
$time = time() - 3600;
$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `trending` WHERE `time` > '$time'");
```

How can I get the top 10 records for 10 different pages ? something like `MAX()` I also want to get the data associated with page such as the name.

Comment: order by count(id) desc

Comment: What does the `id` represent? A web page or a `trending` record? *I also want to get the data associated with page such as the name.* Is that data in `trending` or in another table. If its in another table what the Foreign Key (FK) in `trending`

Comment: Your other question is, I think, a re-ask of this one. I'm suggesting this one for closure, as you've more detail on the other one. Where you have a question, do please only ask it once - it creates duplicate work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

**Group by id & then order by count.**

```
    $mysqli->query("SELECT id, COUNT(`id`) as cnt 
FROM `trending` WHERE `time` > '$time' 
group by id 
order by cnt desc limit 10");
```

Comment: should work. if ordering not works on a calculated column (older mysql) use subquery.

Answer (score 0):

this one helps? (last hour you meant)

```
$time = time() - 3600;
$mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM 'trending' WHERE 'time' > '".$time."' LIMIT 1,10");
```